# Django AutoComplete Light not working with OneToOne Field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-autocomplete-light

I am trying to add auto-complete for the **OneToOneField** in Django admin using [django-autocomplete-light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/). This field is available in Django Rest Framework's [auth_token model](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authtoken/models.py).

```
class Token(models.Model):
    """
    The default authorization token model.
    """
    key = models.CharField(_("Key"), max_length=40, primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='auth_token',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("User")
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(_("Created"), auto_now_add=True)
```

**models.py**

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token


class CustomAuthTokenModel(Token):
    search_fields = ['user', ]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

**views.py**

```
from dal import autocomplete
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token


class AuthUserAutocompleteView(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):

        qs = Token.objects.all().order_by('user__username')

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(user__username__icontains=self.q)

        return qs
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.authtoken.admin import TokenAdmin
from .forms import AuthUserForm


class CustomTokenAdmin(TokenAdmin):
    form = AuthUserForm


admin.site.unregister(Token)
admin.site.register(Token, CustomTokenAdmin)
```

**forms.py**

```
from dal import autocomplete
from .models import CustomAuthTokenModel


class AuthUserForm(autocomplete.FutureModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomAuthTokenModel
        fields = ('user', )
        search_fields = ['user__username']
        widgets = {
            'user': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='autocomplete_auth_user')
        }
```

And in urls.py file, I have:

```
url('^autocomplete_auth_user/$', AuthUserAutocompleteView.as_view(), name='autocomplete_auth_user')
```

I am pretty sure, I must be missing something, because I can't see the user names while entering the form in admin panel for auth token. Let me know what I am missing. I am using Django 1.11 and django-autocomplete light 3.2.10.